# How to turn off LED after a certain interval of time using nrf51822 module

Tags: c, embedded, nrf51, shift-register

There are 12 LEDs which are connected using shift register HC595 ,the module used is nrf51822(bluetooth module). I want the LEDs to go off after 3 seconds interval. My code is as follows-

```
#include "main.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include "nrf_delay.h"
#include "rc522.h"
#include "hc595.h"
#include "tsm12m.h"
#include "iic.h"
#include "app_timer.h"
#define APP_TIMER_PRESCALER              0                                          /**< Value of the RTC1 PRESCALER register. */
#define APP_TIMER_OP_QUEUE_SIZE          6    

APP_TIMER_DEF(LEDOps);
static void timer_a_handler(void * p_context)
{
    lightAllLEDs();
}
static void create_timers()
{  
    uint32_t err_code;

    // Create timers
    err_code = app_timer_create(&LEDOps,
                                APP_TIMER_MODE_SINGLE_SHOT,
                                timer_a_handler);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}
void timers_init(){
    uint32_t err_code;
// Initialize the application timer module.
        APP_TIMER_INIT(APP_TIMER_PRESCALER, APP_TIMER_OP_QUEUE_SIZE, false);
        create_timers();
}
void timer_a_start(){
    uint32_t err_code;
    err_code = app_timer_start(LEDOps, APP_TIMER_TICKS(3,APP_TIMER_PRESCALER), NULL);
  APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}

int main(void)
{
        uartInit();
      TSM12_Init(); 
      HC595_Init();
        timers_init();
        timer_a_start();
      UartSendstring("123456789");   
    printf("timer stopped!!");  
      app_timer_stop(LEDOps);
    while(1)
    {
             TSM12_Handle();
             nrf_delay_ms(1);
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't seem to work. I am new to module. Please help by giving a solution.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" Could you please be a bitmore precise? In what way does it fail?

Comment: I mean the LEDs doesnt turn off after 3 seconds. It stays on.

Comment: I don't know that environment.  But it seems that you stop the timer immediately.

Comment: Where is the code setting the LED? I take it you are bit-banging data and clock at once? Any reason why you aren't using SPI?

Comment: Even if i add a delay, I am still getting the same result. I am using KEIL IDE.

Comment: Lundin can you guide me how to use SPI for this.I want the code to be simple and efficient

Comment: If you are new to the whole environment, first try all the bits and pieces separately. Switch LED on and off without a timer. Then try to use a timer.

Comment: Yes i have done that.

Comment: Thank you everyone.I have solved the problem.

Comment: As this is a Q&A site, it would be useful to share your solution.